# Java Web App Crashing on Heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have an existing Java web app project. I converted it into a maven project and deployed it on Heroku. The application is deployed successfully but it does not run; it crashes. I cannot figure out from the logs what the reason is. my Procfile looks like this:
**web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/m2e-wtp/*.jar**

All I see in the logs is that the app crashed with the error code = H10 with status 503. I would really appreciate help on this.Following are the logs:

```
app[web.1]: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by charan7j86@gmail.com
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fierce-woodland-8040.herokuapp.com request_id=9e462e2f-0e4f-4ef7-a503-e557fa46397a fwd="67.169.27.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fierce-woodland-8040.herokuapp.com request_id=fcfb168d-3c62-4c0b-92ba-0a0418cdc703 fwd="67.169.27.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -XX:+UseCompressedOops -cp target/classes:target/m2e-wtp/*.jar`
app[web.1]: Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
app[web.1]:            (to execute a class)
app[web.1]:    or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
app[web.1]:            (to execute a jar file)
app[web.1]: where options include:
app[web.1]:     -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
app[web.1]:     -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
app[web.1]:                   The default VM is server,
app[web.1]:     -server      to select the "server" VM
app[web.1]:                   because you are running on a server-class machine.
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]:     -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]:     -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
app[web.1]:                   A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
app[web.1]:                   and ZIP archives to search for class files.
app[web.1]:     -D<name>=<value>
app[web.1]:                   set a system property
app[web.1]:     -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
app[web.1]:                   enable verbose output
app[web.1]:     -version      print product version and exit
app[web.1]:     -version:<value>
app[web.1]:                   require the specified version to run
app[web.1]:     -showversion  print product version and continue
app[web.1]:     -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
app[web.1]:                   include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
app[web.1]:     -? -help      print this help message
app[web.1]:     -X            print help on non-standard options
app[web.1]:     -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
app[web.1]:     -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
app[web.1]:                   enable assertions with specified granularity
app[web.1]:     -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
app[web.1]:     -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
app[web.1]:     -esa | -enablesystemassertions
app[web.1]:                   disable assertions with specified granularity
app[web.1]:                   enable system assertions
app[web.1]:     -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
app[web.1]:                   disable system assertions
app[web.1]:     -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
app[web.1]:                   load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
app[web.1]:                   see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
app[web.1]:     -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
app[web.1]:                   load native agent library by full pathname
app[web.1]:     -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
app[web.1]:                   load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
app[web.1]:     -splash:<imagepath>
app[web.1]:                   show splash screen with specified image
app[web.1]: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Can you please show us some of the logs so we can see if there is anything else?  Please clear the logs and run it once and add the logs to the question.

Comment: Please see the logs in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command in your `Procfile` doesn't specify a Main class. It should look like:

```
 web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/m2e-wtp/*.jar com.foo.Main
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since it's a web application, would the main class be the path to the HTML home page?

Comment: No, it will be a Java class with a `public static void main(String[])` method. Are you trying to build a WAR file?

Comment: No. I have created a local git repository with the project files and pushed that repository to the heroku master. It detects the project as java app and builds and deploys it successfully, but cannot run it. It's java web application, there's no main class.

Comment: Is it an executable JAR file? There has to be a main class somewhere -- that just how Java works. Maybe you need jetty-runner or webapp-runner?

Comment: I was able to run the application successfully. I created a war file of the project, specified the path to the HTML home page in the Procfile and deployed it using the war command in Heroku. I was compiling my project against an older version of the Jre than on Heroku which crashed the application. Once I update the version, it ran. Thanks for telling me that I had to specify the path in the Procfile!

Comment: Great! can you accept the answer so others who find this will know?